# What is Haskell diamond symbol?

Tags: haskell, path, ghc

What does this symbol `</>` means in Haskell?

What is it called?

How to use it?

I use ghc 7.8 to compile the application.

Comment: Instead of a downvote how about teaching how to fish? @linquize, http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/ lets you search for symbols too.

Comment: And note it isn't really defined by Haskell as a language but by a library.  You could define your own procedure named `</>` that performs any arbitrary operation, such as formatting your harddrive.

Comment: An alternative to hoogle would be `:i (</>)` in GHCi, which will give you the type of the function and the module it comes from.

Comment: @JeffBurka - because "Top Level: Not in scope" is helpful?

Comment: @Richard If you see this symbol in a file you're looking at, as OP seems to have done, then when you load that file in GHCi, it will be in scope. If you just see it online somewhere, then no GHCi won't be much help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an alias for [combine](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath-1.3.0.2/docs/System-FilePath-Windows.html#v%3acombine).

```
Combine two paths, if the second path isAbsolute, then it returns the second.

Valid x => combine (takeDirectory x) (takeFileName x) `equalFilePath` x
Posix:   combine "/" "test" == "/test"
Posix:   combine "home" "bob" == "home/bob"
Windows: combine "home" "bob" == "home\\bob"
Windows: combine "home" "/bob" == "/bob"
```

Comment: Why? Because ``<>`` is the operator for the ``mappend`` operation which is the generic version of the ``++`` operator. So ``</>`` is meant to look like 'join with slash'.

Comment: I like this function in haskell, in C# we have `Path.Combine()` which is cross-platform too.

Comment: SeanPerry: That's an interesting observation.  I never thought of that.  I wonder if it would make sense for `FilePath` to be a `newtype` and `combine` the `mappend` of its `Monoid` instance ...

Comment: @TomEllis If you'd rather use a `newtype` you might as well go all the way and switch to something like [`system-filepath`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-filepath).

Comment: @duplode: Yes I see that has exactly the behaviour I was thinking of.  Nice.